# Create Map inside local function

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

i have a map of maps as a member of a class.
`map <int,map<int,vector<byte>>> m_`.

Then, somewhere else in the code i need to add an element to this map. 
What i am doing (inside a function) is :

`map<int,vector<byte>> tmp;
 tmp.insert(std::make_pair(1,a_vector));
 m_.insert(1,tmp)`

but will not work, since this tmp is local to the scope of the function. 
How do I create a map that lives outside the local scope?

Comment: Have you tried it? It will work but with a copy/move of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. C++ has value semantics. Sure, `tmp` has local scope. But `m_`  doesn't. And the last insert stores the *value* of `tmp` in `m_`. Just like the *value* of `a_vector` is stored in `tmp`.

Since C++ has value semantics, we usually just write "store X in Y" when we actually mean the value of X.

Answer (score 1):

You're worring about nothing, `map` will either copy or move objects into itself, it doesn't hold references to the objects you add.